# Match the first letter of one column with the first letter of other column and do str_replace after

Tags: r, substr

I have a list of abbreviations and a list of replacements. However, some abbreviations have country index in them. It looks like this:

| Country | Abbr |
| --- | --- |
| US | SP num1 |
| UK | SP num1 |
| Malasia | MSP num2 |
| Albania | ASD num1 |
| Poland | ASD num3 |
| Malasia | first MSP num1 |

The list of abbreviations and replacements:

```
country <- c("US", "UK", "Malasia", "Albania", "Poland")
abbr <- c("SP num1", "SP num1", "MSP num2", "ASD num1", "ASD num3")
words_to_replace <- c("SP", "SD")
replacements <- c("state police", "state duma")
```

What I would like to get is:

| Country | New |
| --- | --- |
| us | state police num1 |
| uk | state police num1 |
| malasia | malasia state police num2 |
| albania | albania state police num1 |
| poland | asd num3 |
| malasia | first malasia state police num1 |

For usual abbreviations I use:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = str_replace_all(abbr, setNames(replacements, words_to_replace)))
```

However, I need to somehow combine it with substr function and I have no idea how to do it. I assume something with if or ifelse might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(stringi) 

df <- data.frame(country, abbr)

df$abbr <- stri_replace_all_regex(df$abbr,
                                  pattern = words_to_replace,
                                  replacement = replacements,
                                  vectorize = FALSE)
```

The result:

```
  country   abbr
1  US       state police num1
2  UK       state police num1
3  Malaysia Mstate police num2
4  Albania  Astate duma num1
5  Poland   Astate duma num3
```

This assumes you wish to retain the "M" and "A" in the abbr column, as this what would happen if you employed your current list objects. To achieve your desired result, you'll need to change them to something like:

```
words_to_replace <- c(".*SP", ".*SD")
replacements <- c("state police", "state duma")
```

with the result:

```
  country   abbr
1 US        state police num1
2 UK        state police num1
3 Malaysia  state police num2
4 Albania   state duma num1
5 Poland    state duma num3
```

Then if you require "Malaysia" and "Albania", you can use `paste()` to concatenate the strings from the country columns. However, @onyambu provides a better solution to your desired output as it retains the "ASD" values for Poland.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(abbr1 = str_sub(country, 1,1),
          abbr2 =abbr1 %>% 
           str_remove(abbr, .) %>% 
           str_replace_all(setNames(replacements, 
                        str_c("\\b",words_to_replace,"\\b"))) %>% 
           ifelse(abbr1 == str_sub(abbr, 1, 1), str_c(country, .,sep = ' '), .))

  country     abbr abbr1                     abbr2
1      US  SP num1     U         state police num1
2      UK  SP num1     U         state police num1
3 Malasia MSP num2     M Malasia state police num2
4 Albania ASD num1     A   Albania state duma num1
5  Poland ASD num3     P                  ASD num3
```

Comment: Achieves the OPs desired result succinctly. This is very useful.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. However, I understood that my data sometimes has abbreviations in the middle of the string like: "first MSP num1". Do you know what can be done in this case?